# Multivariate stats

Tags: categorical-data, multivariate-analysis

I have the following data to analyse and not sure what the best method would be. I have percent coverage data for several invasive plant species. as well as several variables including  different land uses and road types from where these species have been sampled. What multivariate method would be best to analyse this simultaneously? Also, do I need to do it separately for each species?

Thanks

Comment: note that these percentages aren't independent (since they can't total more than 100% in any location).

Comment: Ok thanks, but what exactly does that mean?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're after. Do you mean "what does 'not independent' mean" or something else? Are you after what the consequences of the non-independence are for some as-yet-unspecified analysis?

Comment: I understand the 'not independent' part but not sure why you are saying this because it does not really answer any of my previous questions. Can I do PCA or CCA multivariate stats or use MANOVA with the above mentioned data? I have not worked with multivariate stats before, only ANOVA's and general linear models. Thanks

Comment: It wasn't intended to be an answer, it was intended as a 'heads up' to anyone considering providing an answer that there's an important issue that might otherwise be easily missed. At least some of the techniques you mention assume independence.

Answer (score 0):

You can do CCA if you want to attribute variation just to the factors of the study
(PCA just condenses species information to fewer axes but can be followed up with multiple regression on the resulting axes). The answer to the second question depends on the point of your study: interested in the overall variability in invasive spp community structure or species-specific responses?